# Kubernetes Test Dome

Tags: kubernetes

Can’t figure out what I am messing up in the kubernetes yaml. The part that is messed up is the app:nginx part. Below is the question

The team responsible for Kubernetes wants to add a Deployment that will deploy 4 nginx Pods which should have port 443 open. Finish the following YAML configuration so that it implements those requirements

[image of yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyxzx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

At Spec.template.label section you need to give web:public, because either in metadata or spec matchlabels mentioned as web : Public.
So, here also you need to pass the same then only yaml script works.
[Refer to this doc for more information](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

Below image with 100% pass:

[Image of yaml](https://ibb.co/Yjry2Wk)